# How do I set up attribute routing for a PUT with web-api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to set up attribute routing:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/Config/Put")]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(Config config) {
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }
}
```

Here's what I created. My question is do I have to do anything to specify the `config` that I am sending to the method ? Also is it possible to just specify this as a method for the controller rather than decorate each method?

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

in your WebApiConfig

so it will be like this now

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```

For your second question : you have some thing called   `[RoutePrefix("api")]` attribute  which  you can add to controller so that this part becomes common for all methods . In our case "api" is the common one

Comment: I already have what you suggest. What I want to do is to decorate the controllers / routest.